# Creating Nested tabBox in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to create a shinydashboard dashboard with 2 top level tabs, **TabOne** and **TabTwo** where the toplevel Tab **TabOne** has two nested tabs **InnerOne** and **InnerTwo**. I have attempted the code below, but the output is rather mangled:

```r
library(shinydashboard)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'shinydashboard'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     box
library(shiny)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabBox(
    id="tabBox1",
    tabPanel("TabOne",
             tabBox(
               id="innerBox",
               tabPanel("InnerOne","inner1"),
               tabPanel("InnerTwo","inner2"),
             )),
    tabPanel("TabTwo","2"),
  )
  
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "tabBoxes"),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    body
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    
  }
)
#> PhantomJS not found. You can install it with webshot::install_phantomjs(). If it is installed, please make sure the phantomjs executable can be found via the PATH variable.
```

Shiny applications not supported in static R Markdown documents

<sup>Created on 2023-10-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>